# How do I add lamda expressions in transverse function?

Tags: haskell

I am new in Haskell and I am working with map function and lambda expressions. Using map I made a function of transverse and I want to add lambda expressions but I get confused and It can't work.

**Code:**

```
tfunc :: [Int] -> [Int]
tfunc xs = map tfunc1 xs
           where tfunc1 x = x*3+x
```

**Output:**

```
F17BCSE206>tfunc [1,2,3,4,5]
[4,8,12,16,20] :: [Int]
```

I want to use lambda expressions. Can anybody help me and use lambda expression in the given function.

Comment: You mean `map (\x -> x*3 + x) xs`?

Comment: Yes. Can it works?

Comment: pedantically: `x*3 + x` is just `x*4`, and the function `\x -> x*4` is just `(*4)`

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that a function definition like `tfunc1 x = ...` is just syntactic sugar for binding a name to a lambda expression, so `tfunc1 = \x -> ...`. Then, since the two sides of `=` can be used interchangeably, you can simply replace

```
tfunc1 xs = map tfunc1 xs where tfunc1 = \x -> x*3 + x
```

with

```
tfunc1 xs = map (\x -> x*3 + x) xs where tfunc1 = \x -> x*3 + x
```

Since the `where` clause is now completely extraneous, you can simply drop it.

```
tfunc1 xs = map (\x -> x*3 + x) xs
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. It really works and your description made my confusion clear.